# resizing table to match others

Tags: tables, tabularx

The table below spans the whole page and so its huge, I was wondering what I am missing to make the text size 11 and so get the table to reconfigure accordingly. I guess its something to do with my \resizebox code but not sure what I need to put to correct it.

thank you

Packages and table code:

```
    - \usepackage{tabularx}
    - \usepackage{graphicx}

    \begin{table}[h!]
    \centering
    \resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
    \begin{tabular}{|c|}
    \hline
    Organisations Name \\
    \hline
    U.S. Chamber of Commerce \\
    National Association of Manufacturers \\
    American Council of Life Insurers \\ 
    National Insurance Association \\
    Securities and investment companies \\
    American Hospital Association \\
    Tobbaco companies \\
    Airlines \\
    Automobile companies \\
    Defense contractors \\
    National Federation of Independent Businesses \\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}}
    \caption{Subset of groups to represent business interests }
    \label{table:3}
    \end{table}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX. Never use `\resizebox` with tables: it leads to inconsistent font sizes. Could you post a compilable code that shows the problems you have?

Comment: I am not sure what exactly you mean by "a compilable code"

Comment: Some full code we can compile, without having to add a preamble from scratch.

Comment: What exactly is the problem, anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see no (valid) reason for enlarging the `tabular` so that it spans the full width of the text block. I'd left-align the material in the table, I'd omit all vertical bars, and I'd use only well-spaced horizontal lines. Use a `threeparttable` environment if it's important that the caption be no wider than the tabular material.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,threeparttable}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h!]
\centering % optional
\begin{threeparttable} % force caption to have same width as tabular
\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}
\toprule
Organisation Names \\
\midrule
U.S. Chamber of Commerce \\
National Association of Manufacturers \\
American Council of Life Insurers \\ 
National Insurance Association \\ 
Securities and investment companies \\
American Hospital Association \\
Tobbaco companies \\
Airlines \\ 
Automobile companies \\
Defense contractors \\
National Federation of Independent Businesses \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{Subset of groups to represent business interests }
\label{table:3}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```